# CMD file - delayed variable expansion

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, cmd

I am writing a CMD/batch file (running under Win-7 cmd.exe) and I seem to be getting hung up on delayed variable expansion.

I am using text file input that is in the form:

> 9 .CN=ISRJX.OU=Linc.OU=thisco.O=UCOM.T=UCOM.  8-20-13
>
> 10 .CN=FXXLISHER.OU=Linc.OU=thisco.O=UCOM.T=UCOM. 10-13-13
>
> 11 .CN=QXX004F.OU=Linc.OU=thisco.O=UCOM.T=UCOM.   10-14-13
>
> 12 *.CN=QXX1001OB.OU=Linc.OU=thisco.O=UCOM.T=UCOM.    10-15-13

as contents in "inputfile.txt".  Purpose is to extract the first word after ".CN=", at this point in the process.

Note that I can't strip based on number of chars before "CN=" because the number of chars will vary.

My script is:

```
setlocal enableextensions enableDelayedExpansion
REM @echo off
for /f "tokens=3 delims==." %%a in (inputfile.txt) do (
set "acct =%%a"
echo. %%a,%acct%
)
endlocal
```

I've tried every set of combination of quote, !, % etc. and both enabled & disabled delayed expansion, and still can't get this to work.  For the most part, when I use ! I end up echoing the actual !.  i.e. `"echo !acct!"` will echo the actual text "!acct!".

I have read many examples and answers, here and elsewhere, about delayed variable expansion.  I just can't figure out how to work around it in this example, where I want "acct" to expand within the loop.

Suspect this is a simple punctuation problem, but I'm out of ideas.  When I run this, I see acct set to the value for %%a, but when it echoes, clearly it doesn't expand to the new value -- instead it will echo whatever it was set to previously, or blank.

I have also tried `disabledelayedexpansion`, which makes no difference in my results (including when I use `!acct!` instead of `%acct%`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Remove the space after the acct variable name and use the ! marks.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=3 delims==." %%A in (inputfile.txt) do (
    set "acct=%%A"
    echo. %%A,!acct!
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Drat, I knew it was punctuation!  I presume the effect was naming the variable "acct " (space included as part of the name.)  I had tried the "!acct!" before, but due to the space error in the var name, it was just echoing "!acct!" as text.  This works now.  Thank you for ameliorating the accelerated silvering of my tresses.